# Is $y\;dx$ the area under a point?

Tags: calculus

> Is $y\;dx$ the area under a point?

**Context**: trying to understand basic calculus, particularly the fundamental theorem.

I assume this is an elementary question; if not I can give more of the background and reasoning that motivates it.

Comment: What do you mean by the area under a point?

Comment: @PeterForeman I mean $\lim_{\Delta x \mapsto 0} (y \; \Delta x$).

Comment: Yeah, you can say it’s the area under an arbitrary point and forming a rectangle such that it’s height is y and base is dx.

Comment: @mjc That limit is just zero as is the 'area under a point'.

Comment: Area under a point means at least in calculus as the area of a rectangle with a differential base (differential element of a length of x)

Comment: @PeterForeman Is there a standard interpretation of $y \; dx$? I'm picturing it as a differential rectangle.

Comment: @mjc The standard interpretation is algebraic and pretty unintuitive w/o a strong understanding of exterior algebra. I think what you have is fine.

Comment: @DonThousand Yes you’re right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $dx$ being the base and $y$ being the height, $ydx$ is the area of the rectangular bar over $dx$ with fixed hieght of $y$.

The limiting  process comes next when the Riemann's Sum approaches the integral.